# Regular Expression for a character not appearing between double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I need a regular expression to check if a character doesn't appear in double quotes("). For example, if i have something like `<b>"ABC<DEF"</b>`, then the regular expression should match `<` of both the tags and it should not match `<` between the double quotes.

Comment: You must not be explaining your goal correctly. *Characters not appearing between double quotes* in your example: `b`, `>`, `/` – yet you say the RegEx should match `<`?

Comment: Are you trying to simply remove HTML tags? Maybe this post can help? http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant "should NOT match < between the double quotes". In this case, a lookahead does the trick:

```
s = '<b>"ABC<DEF" match<this "ignore<this" end'
s.replace(/<(?=("[^"]*"|[^"]+)+$)/g, "@")

// "@b>"ABC<DEF" match@this "ignore<this" end"
```

Comment: When i used the same function on `<b>"ABC<DEF"</b>`, it replaced only first `<` i.e. the resulting string was `@b>"ABC`. Why this is so? The expected resulting string should be `@b>"ABC<DEF"@/b>`.

Comment: @user2546340: sure? I'm getting correct results. Care to make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake. Its giving correct resulting string.